# Sharing data between different apps in the same iOS device

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

Is it possible to share any kind of data between two apps in the same device without having to rely on an external service and/or udids?

Comment: what kind of data are you trying to share?

Comment: Just things like, "user bought game A, user bought game B" etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Keychain Service Groups](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/4/3/keychain-group-access.html) for sharing small amounts of data among your own apps.

Answer (score 2):

For small amounts of data, you can have both apps register custom URL handlers, and have the apps launch each other with the data to share encoded as part of the URL string.